# Nestjs azure active directory and graphql - UseGuard

Tags: graphql, azure-active-directory, passport.js, nestjs

Building an API with nestjs and graphql I want to implement Azure Active Directory for authorization.
They provide a  `passport-azure-ad` package with a strategy.
It is working just fine when I add a nestjs guard to a REST endpoint, but with a GrapQL resolver it is throwing an error `Cannot read property 'query' of undefined`.

Nestjs [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/authentication#graphql) give some hint, but I have no idea how to implement and make the graphql query available to the passport strategy.

My guard looks as follows:

```
import { Injectable } from '@nestjs/common';
import { PassportStrategy, AuthGuard } from '@nestjs/passport';
import { BearerStrategy } from 'passport-azure-ad';
import * as dotenv from 'dotenv';
dotenv.config();

const clientID = process.env.AZURE_AD_CLIENT_ID;
const tenantID = process.env.AZURE_AD_TENANT_ID;

/**
 * Extracts ID token from header and validates it.
 */
@Injectable()
export class AzureADStrategy extends PassportStrategy(
  BearerStrategy,
  'azure-ad',
) {
  constructor() {
    super({
      identityMetadata: `https://login.microsoftonline.com/${tenantID}/v2.0/.well-known/openid-configuration`,
      clientID,
    });
  }
  
  async validate(data) {
    console.log(data);
    return data;
  }
}

export const AzureADGuard = AuthGuard('azure-ad');
```

GraphQL config from `app.module.ts`

```
...
imports: [
 GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      autoSchemaFile: join(process.cwd(), 'src/schema.gql'),
      sortSchema: true,
      context: ({ req }) => ({ req }),
    }),
...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The passport strategy is *probably* looking for the `query` parameter of `request`, which isn't immediately available from a GQL request. To fix this, you can make a custom guard that `extends AuthGuard('azure-ad')` and override the `getRequest()` method to return the incoming `req` object with the following method:

```js
@Injectable()
export class AzureADGuard extends AuthGuard('azure-ad') {
  getRequest(context: ExecutionContext) {
    const gql = GqlExecutionContext.create(context);
    return gql.getContext().req;
  }
}
```

Comment: That was it. The custom guard can now be used for the GraphQL queries and the "pure" Guard from my post can be used for the REST queries as well